# If this equation can't be solved algebraically, can it be solved some other way?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I'm studying for SOA/CAS Exam P and I have boiled down a problem to say $e^{-\lambda}\left(1+\lambda +\frac{\lambda ^2}{2}\right)=\frac23$. I was stuck after this and assumed there was a way to solve it. However the solutions say it cannot be solved algabraically and rather I should substitute each of the 5 possible choices until one of them satisfies. Which got me wondering if there is a way to solve this using some kind of other method?

Comment: There's is no algebraic solution, only numerical (that is, approximate) methods, like the secant method, and Newton's Method.

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations